# History pushstate and fallback for IE9 problems

Tags: jquery, pushstate

I use `history.pushstate` to load content and have a fallback for IE9 and prior, but im having issues that i cant find working solutions for by googling. Ive read a lot of posts on the topic, but most of them seems to be missing important information -  I should say that I'm not JavaScript/jQuery-expert at all.

I know that its possible to use routers like Backbone.js, History.js, Path.js etc - this is not what im looking for - id would like to fully understand how to set up the code in my own script.

Im posting ALL of the code except styling - this might be of help to others trying to acchieve a working solution for AJAX loading with pushstate + fallback.

**Issues with the history.pushstate (the .."if" in script):**

1. How do i rewrite the URL making it possible to bookmark and do a page refresh?

**Issues with the fallback method (.."else" in script):**

1. URL changes in IE9 when pressing back-/forward-buttons, but content
   doesnt reload - how can i reload the content using the existing
   code?
2. How do i rewrite the URL making it possible to bookmark and
   do a page refresh?

**On top of that,** im having trouble adressing pages placed in a subfolder (and sub-sub-folder) - where do i put the ("/") in my existing code?

I know especially the URL rewriting may not have a simple answer - i have tested with some .htaccess mod_rewrite on WAMP, but i cant make it work - im missing something in the process..

Heres the working script i have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if (typeof(window.history.pushState) == 'function') {

// AJAX-LOADING
$('a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');

    history.pushState({ path: (page + ".html")}, '', page);     // ("/") - url for absolute links in subfolders where?
    $("#content").load(page + ".html");
    return false;
});

// BACKBUTTON
$(window).bind('popstate', function(event) {
    var state = event.originalEvent.state;
    if (state) {
        $("#content").load(state.path);
    }
});

//  FALLBACK IE9
} else {
$('a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');

    window.location.hash = page + ".html"; 
    $("#content").load(page + ".html");
    return false;
});

} // END of if.. and else.. 

}); // END DOC READY
```

This is the index.html:

```
<body>
<div id="main">
    <h1>this is index.html</h1>

<ul>
    <li><a href="page1">Load page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2">Load page 2</a></li>  
</ul>

<div id="content">
<p>Load here.....</p><br />
    </div>
</div>  <!--    end of main -->       
</body>
```

page1.html is:

```
<h1> page 1 - this is </h1>
```

page2.html is:

```
<h1> this is the 2. page </h1>
```

Comment: Personally, i would just fallback to full page reloads rather than the hash, however if you must use the hash, you'll need to add functionality to catch when the hash changes. There is a hashChange event, however, not all versions of IE support it. In the ones that don't, you'll have to use an ugly setInterval. If you look at the source of history.js, you'll see how this is done. I don't quite understand why you feel you must "reinvent the wheel" in this case, history.js is already about as barebones as it can get, and it's thoroughly tested all the way back to IE6.

Comment: @KevinB - History.js on IE9 the url gets messed up.. I get the url change from www.domain.com/abc.php adding the id to www.domain.com/abc.php?#abc.php?id=1... have u ever faced that ?

Comment: Yes, i'm pretty sure that's how history.js implements it for browsers that don't support the pushstate.